# why my circularProgressIndicator having strange behavior when async function called?

Tags: flutter

Im calling a function to get data from Excel file and upload it to my Firestore as following

```
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {

            Utils.showLoading(context);

            await FireStoreServices.bulkUploadFromExcelToFireStore(
                collectionName: 'test',
                fileName: 'test',
                sheetName: 'test');
            Navigator.pop(context);

          }),
```

the problem is my Progress loading indicator not working as expected in this case (not spinning only shows and freeze until the function complete after that its popped)
[image: loading indicator not spinning]

i tried to replace the awaited function 'bulkUploadFromExcelToFireStore' with Future.delayed and it worked as expected

```
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
```

[image: loading indicator spinning and working as expected]

**what might be the problem ?**

here is the code of bulkUploadFromExcelToFireStore function

```
  static Future bulkUploadFromExcelToFireStore(
  {required String fileName,
  required String sheetName,
  required String collectionName}) async {
try {
  final rowsData = await Utils.readExcelFileData(
      excelFilePath: fileName, sheetName: sheetName);
  rowsData.removeAt(0);
  
  for (var row in rowsData) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection(collectionName).doc(row[0]).set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Cached ERROR MESSAGE = = = = ${e.toString()}');
}
```

Comment: You might be doing too much work on the main thread. Reading all the data into memory on this thread might be quite intensive. Check with the profiler for certain spikes. You might want to move some work to another Isolate to upload.

Answer (score 0):

I added some validations inside your function to check for possible failures.

It would also be interesting to validate a failure warning and terminate the Progression Indication initialization.

```
static Future<String> bulkUploadFromExcelToFireStore({required String fileName, required String sheetName,required String collectionName}) async {
 try {
  final rowsData = await Utils.readExcelFileData(excelFilePath: fileName, sheetName: sheetName);
  rowsData.removeAt(0);
    
  if(rowsData.length == 0) {
   return "No Items!";
  } else {
   for (var row in rowsData) {
    firebaseFirestore?.collection(collectionName)?.doc(row[0])?.set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
   }
    
   return "Item allocated!";
  }
 } catch (e) {
  return e.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: i have no problem with the function its working fine and im getting the result i want, my only problem is the unexpected behavior of CircularloadingIndicator widget on the screen otherwise everything is working fine